# Soundtrack in Bleach episode 358 at around 8:45?

Tags: music, bleach

It starts around 8:40, before Ginjo throws the Combat Pass to Ichigo and tells him 'Here. Give it a try'.

I've looked everywhere but I can't find it. This song has been played multiple times in the series, mostly in the latter arcs I think.

Answer (score 1):

Song is caleld 'Mysterious' : https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=21&v=hfHdV5NaIhA .

Took me a while, but if you have the patience to look through this list http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Music?file=Bleach_-_*Asterisk-0 you should find any song, unless unreleased, which you might find googling